# Interpolate variables on subsets of dataframe

Tags: r, plyr

I have a large dataframe which has observations from surveys from multiple states for several years. Here's the data structure:

```
state | survey.year | time1 | obs1 | time2 | obs2
CA    | 2000        | 1     | 23   | 1.2   | 43
CA    | 2001        | 2     | 43   | 1.4   | 52
CA    | 2002        | 5     | 53   | 3.2   | 61
...
CA    | 1998        | 3     | 12   | 2.3   | 20
CA    | 1999        | 4     | 14   | 2.8   | 25
CA    | 2003        | 5     | 19   | 4.3   | 29
...
ND    | 2000        | 2     | 223   | 3.2   | 239
ND    | 2001        | 4     | 233   | 4.2   | 321
ND    | 2003        | 7     | 256   | 7.9   | 387
```

For each state/survey.year combination, I would like to interpolate obs2 so that it's time-location is lined up with (time1,obs1).

ie I would like to break up the dataframe into state/survey.year chunks, perform my linear interpolation, and then stitch the individual state/survey.year dataframes back together into a master dataframe.

I have been trying to figure out how to use the plyr and Hmisc packages for this. But keeping getting myself in a tangle.

Here's the code that I wrote to do the interpolation:

```
require(Hmisc)
df <- new.obs2 <- NULL
for (i in 1:(0.5*(ncol(indirect)-1))){
 df[,"new.obs2"] <-   approxExtrap(df[,"time1"],
                                     df[,"obs1"],
                                     xout = df[,"obs2"],
                                     method="linear",
                                     rule=2)
}
```

But I am not sure how to unleash plyr on this problem. Your generous advice and suggestions would be much appreciated. Essentially - I am just trying to interpolate "obs2", within each state/survey.year combination, so it's time references line up with those of "obs1".

Of course if there's a slick way to do this without invoking plyr functions, then I'd be open to that...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should be as simple as,

```
ddply(df,.(state,survey.year),transform,
                              new.obs2 = approxExtrap(time1,obs1,xout = obs2,
                                                      method = "linear",
                                                      rule = 2))
```

But I can't promise you anything, since I haven't the foggiest idea what the point of your `for` loop is. (It's overwriting `df[,"new.obs2"]` each time through the loop? You initialize the entire data frame `df` to `NULL`? What's `indirect`?)