# R: Interpolation multiple columns by group using target values column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, interpolation

Have a 15x6 dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(PART = c("A7","A7","A7","A7","A7","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A7","A7","A7","A7","A7"),
                 LIMIT = c(50,50,50,50,50,55,55,55,55,55,52.5,52.5,52.5,52.5,52.5),
                 MEAS = c(14.008,19.053,22.244,24.554,25.521,18.495,22.3,24.867,26.825,27.169,15.299,20.239,23.384,25.606,26.516),
                 MEAS_TARGET = c(16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,21.2,21.2,21.2,21.2,21.2,21.5,21.5,21.5,21.5,21.5),
                 INT = c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5,2,3,4,5,5.2,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5),
                 COL = c(-31.845,-25.51,-21.377,-18.537,-17.546,-41.1,-39.294,-36.813,-33.779,-33.361,-53.589,-49.664,-46.836,-43.581,-40.64))
```

I am trying to group by `PART` and `LIMIT` columns and using linear interpolation find the missing values in `INT` and `COL` columns when `MEAS = MEAS_TARGET` and create the following 18x6 dataframe result:

```
result <- data.frame(PART = c("A7","A7","A7","A7","A7","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A7","A7","A7","A7","A7","A7","A1","A7"),
                 LIMIT = c(50,50,50,50,50,55,55,55,55,55,52.5,52.5,52.5,52.5,52.5,50,55,52.5),
                 MEAS = c(14.008,19.053,22.244,24.554,25.521,18.495,22.3,24.867,26.825,27.169,15.299,20.239,23.384,25.606,26.516,16.5,21.2,21.5),
                 MEAS_TARGET = c(16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,21.2,21.2,21.2,21.2,21.2,21.5,21.5,21.5,21.5,21.5,16.5,21.2,21.5),
                 INT = c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5,2,3,4,5,5.2,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5,1.99,2.7,2.9),
                 COL = c(-31.845,-25.51,-21.377,-18.537,-17.546,-41.1,-39.294,-36.813,-33.779,-33.361,-53.589,-49.664,-46.836,-43.581,-40.64,-28.716,-39.816,-48.53))
```

I tried to create NA rows for each group and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696795/r-interpolation-of-nas-by-group) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624499/interpolate-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-r) but couldn't make it work. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete` to include new rows where  `MEAS = MEAS_TARGET` and interpolate `INT` and `COL` columns with `zoo::na.approx`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PART, LIMIT) %>%
  complete(MEAS = unique(c(MEAS, MEAS_TARGET))) %>%
  mutate(across(c(INT, COL), zoo::na.approx)) %>%
  fill(MEAS_TARGET) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: thanks, that's the solution I was looking for.

Comment: one question: when `MEAS_TARGET` is smaller than `MEAS` I get an error. for example replacing `16.5` with `13.5` in `MEAS_TARGET` column. is there a fix for that?

Comment: You can set `na.rm = FALSE` in `na.approx`, since there are no values to interpolate it will remain `NA`. `mutate(across(c(INT, COL), zoo::na.approx, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%`